# SQL Impala remove duplicates based on two or more columns and return all

Tags: sql, duplicates, distinct, impala

How can I remove duplicates based on two or more (out of many) columns of a table and still return all the columns, eg using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3 
FROM table
```

and get back `col1,col2,col3,col4,col5...` and so on?

I cannot do it, because the `DISTINCT` statement can only go first after `SELECT` and cannot combine with `*`.

If there is an alternative without the `DISTINCT` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of analytical function row_number to get the desired query output.

```
select * from (
select col1,col2,..
      ,row_number() over(partition by col1,col2 order by col1 desc /*any order by column will suffice*/) as rnk
  from table1)y
where y.rnk=1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works. One question though. I want to simply keep the first observation for each combination of same columns. Is this the default with this function? Also how does order by affects my final table? Thanks!

Comment: the order by will determine which is the first observation that you wish to keep. If you would like to keep the earliest datetime column, then you would order by datetimecolumn desc